# How to perform Unicode equivalence checks / normalization in Java

Tags: java, string, unicode

In my work I often have to compare strings and names to one another, and I recently came across the concept of [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) which may help generalize many of the operations we do today manually, and maybe solve a lot of other edge cases.

My question is: how can I perform Unicode normalization or Unicode-equivalent comparison of strings according to the rules defined in the unicode equivalence specification in Java.

A brief search in stackoverflow/Google/Apache commons-text library didn't produce any results for tools that would allow me to do so.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html

Comment: Yes. And here's the most relevant class: [Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html). It's all built-in. No additional libraries required.

Comment: Stop using Wikipedia as a trusted source. See [Canonical and Compatibility Equivalence](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Canon_Compat_Equivalence)…

Comment: @Codo if any of your would write it as an answer with basic explanation I will accept it

Comment: @DeanGurvitz [1] Since your issue seems to be resolved, but nobody has posted an answer, please consider posting a self-answer, and accepting it. That is much more helpful to the SO community than having an unanswered question. [2] As a separate matter, be aware that [each Java release supports a specific version of Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html) which may impact your code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75648995/2985643) for a recent question on that.

Comment: Please be aware that normalization and equivalence comparison are not that strongly related. There are many equivalence classes defined in Unicode that go way beyond normalization.

Comment: It's weird to me that this question was closed. It is obvious from the content that I wasn't just looking for some general recommendations on a topic, but rather asking how to perform very specific actions, specifically in Java. I changed the phrasing so hopefully emphasize it even further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on what's written in the comments, the built in [Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Normalizer.html) contains both an `isNormalized` and `normalize` methods. The `normalize` method receives an argument of the `Normalizer.Form` enum type allowing you to specify how you want to normalize. Example:

```
System.out.println(Normalizer.normalize("Some text", Normalizer.Form.NFKD)
```

Also, as noted [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html), each Java release supports a specific version of Unicode with its own standards regarding normalizations.